# Javascript json error Invalid JSON primitive: strJson

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I've written a jQuery demo to post JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "RoleFunc.aspx/Vonvert",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { "strJson": json },                   

    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);    
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

and when I use the function, Firebug view shows as an error message like `Invalid JSON primitive: strJson.`

I've tested the JSON and the result is

```
{ "strJsonssss":[{"Role_ID":"2","Customer_ID":"155","Brands":"Chloe;","Country_ID":"96;"}]}
```

and my C# func is

```
[WebMethod]
public static int Vonvert(string strJson)
{
    //DataSet dt1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(strJsonssss);   

    return 1;
}
```

I debug it, and it never in to the function so... any body help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing quote:

```
{ "strJsonssss":[{"Role_ID":"2","Customer_ID":"155","Brands":"Chloe;","Country_ID":"96;"}]}
--------------^
```

Comment: sorry ..i miss the closing quote when i ask it...~~it already have

Comment: i have no idea what you mean, but if your problem is solved, then i'm happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can validate and verify your json objects using this online tool .http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter